# Loop through array ; find and display modulus

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm retrieving records from a .json file, that I'm generating with node.js (with fs, ejs, http, request, connect modules) ;

That's the code I'm using to retrieve the records:

```
<% layers.forEach(function(layer) { %>
<div class="dr-container" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(<%= layer.angle %>deg);">
<% for (j = 1; j <= layer.repeat; j++) { %>
<div class="dr-box" style="height: <%= 100 / layer.repeat %>%;background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<%= layer.linetype %><%= layer.swatch %>');"></div><% } %></div>
<% }); %>
```

(*layers* is the array I'm pulling info from ; *angle, repeat, linetype, swatch* are the fields from the input form on the template. The loop inside the div is meant to repeat the same result a certain number of times and it's working well)

What can I do to retrieve the remainder of all records divided by 6, and show only those?

Like having 38 records and showing the last 2. I understood I need a loop before the 1st line that triggers that?

Comment: `layers.slice(- (layers.length % 6)).forEach(…`

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I pasted and it seems to show all records once there's no remainder. When there's a remainder it shows no records. Then I try add 1, and it shows this one. I try once more and it also works. On the third try it shows all records again. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bergi: nice, but it won't work when the modulus is 0: slice(-0) is the whole array. To fix, use

```
layers.slice(layers.length - layers.length%6).forEach(...
```

Comment: Thanks, with yours and @bergi 's help I realized I have another problem:

(you can visualize the project here: [link](http://jd-noodlemaker.nodejitsu.com)

What happens is that whenever I add this 6th layer it resets the page. This is correct, but I would like to be able to show the result of the 6th layer.

Since I need to submit the form in order to arrive at this blank page (when the modulus is 0), I wonder if this page couldn't show the last 6 layers? Then when the next layer is added (the 1st of this new group of 6, it would be displayed rather than a blank page.

Comment: I *think* I understand what you mean, and if I do then what you need is to replace `layers.length%6` on the right-hand-side of the minus operator within the parenthesis by `(layers.length%6 || 6)`, including the parenthesis. The expression becomes: `layers.slice(layers.length - (layers.length%6 || 6)).forEach(...`

Comment: Yes, that was very precise!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something that will give me same thing but not only using index from array but arbitrary position that can go infinity (ie +100 - 100) so i just added one line to code above in this case -12. If someone needed it.

```
function carousel(array, arbitraryIndex, n) {
var result = [];
index = arbitraryIndex % (array.length);
for (var i = index - n, len = array.length; i <= index + n; i++) {
    result.push(array[i < 0 ? len + i : i > len - 1 ? i - len : i]);
}

return result;
}

var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
arbitraryIndex = -12,
n = 3;

console.log(carousel(array, arbitraryIndex, n));
```